# Vue.js 2.0 - Passing arguments in methods AJAX Axios

Tags: ajax, vue.js, axios

I need to pass an arguments in methods using ajax axios.

```
    var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {

        urlAdmission: 
        admissions: [
                        { name : 'asdf'},
                        { name : 'sd'}
                    ]
    },
    mounted: function(){
        this.allAdmissions()

    },
    methods: {

        allAdmissions: _.debounce( function(){
            var app = this
            axios.get('http://localhost/school/api/hello')
                .then( function(response ){
                    app.admissions = response.data.admissions
                })
                .catch( function(error){
                    console.log(error)
                })
        })
    }
});
```

As you can see in mounted I call the methods this.allAdmissions() I need to pass an argument so that I can reuse the function. For example this.allAdmissions('http://localhost/school/api/hello'). Then use it in axios.get('url'). Thanks

Comment: All you need is `_.debounce(function(url){}, delay)`. Debounce will pass along the parameters.

Comment: Can i pass it like this.allAdmission('htpp://localhost/school/api/hello') then invoke it using _.debounce(function(url), 500). Is this correct?

Comment: Are you trying to create a function that can be reused or just make sure that the function will only execute once every half a second?

Comment: Thanks it works! So easy solution...

Comment: Yeah I think folks were just a little confused.

Comment: Last question @BertEvans `mounted: function(){
  var app = this
  this.allAdmissions('http://localhost/school/api/admissions', app.admissions)
 },
 methods: {

  allAdmissions: _.debounce( function(url, value){
   
   axios.get(url)
    .then( function(response ){
     value = response.data.admissions

    })
    .catch( function(error){
     console.log(error)
    })
  })
 }` I passed an app.admissions and it doesn't work.

Comment: Pass just `app` instead of `app.admissions`, then `value.admissions = response.data.admissions` will stick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you're trying to do is make a function that can accept a url and bind the results of the url to a variable value in your data. Here is how you might do that.

```
methods: { 
  allAdmissions: _.debounce(function(url, value){ 
    axios.get(url)
      .then(function(response){ 
        this[value] = response.data.admissions 
      }.bind(this)) 
      .catch(function(error){ 
        console.log(error) 
      }) 
  })
}
```

Then, if you call that method like this,

```
this.allAdmissions('http://localhost/school/api/admissions‌​', "admissions")
```

`allAdmissions` will set the `admissions` property on your data to the result of your call. This works if you always want to use `response.data.admissions` because you hardcoded that. If you wanted that to be variable as well, you might pass in a third value like so

```
methods: { 
  getSomeData: _.debounce(function(url, value, responseValue){ 
    axios.get(url)
      .then(function(response){ 
        this[value] = response.data[responseValue] 
      }.bind(this)) 
      .catch(function(error){ 
        console.log(error) 
      }) 
  })
}
```

Comment: Yeah it's working now. I just added `var app=this` and `app[value]=response.data.admissions` but I know it will work on the third paramater. Thank you so much for not giving up! You're a rockstar!

Answer (score 0):

In case some will need multiple ajax request. Here is an example.

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        value: '',
        admissions: [],
        schoolyear: []
    },

    created: function(){

        this.ajaxAll()

    },
    methods: {

        ajaxAll: _.debounce( function(){
            var app = this
            var admissions = 'admissions'
            var schoolYear = 'schoolyear'
            axios.all([this.getAllData('http://localhost/school/api/admissions', 'admissions'), this.getAllData('http://localhost/school/api/schoolyear', 'schoolyear')]);


        }),

        getAllData: function(url, value){
            var app = this
            return axios.get(url)
                .then(function(response){
                    app[value] = response.data[value]
                    console.log(response.data.admissions)
                })
        }

    }
})
```

Credit to @Bert Evans.